# How to import the ReadabilityStatistics funtion in this code?

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I have a code which selects multiple Word files and opens them along with logging their path in an Excel file. This code is linked to a Command Button in an Excel form. The code is given below:

```
 Dim DocStats As String
 Dim WordFileName As String


  Call Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).Filters.Clear
 Call Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).Filters.Add( _
 "Word Files Only", "*.docx")

 'allow the user to select multiple files
 Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).AllowMultiSelect = True
 'make the file dialog visible to the user
 intChoice = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).Show
 'determine what choice the user made
 If intChoice <> 0 Then
'get the file path selected by the user
For i = 1 To Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen _
    ).SelectedItems.Count
    strPath = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen _
    ).SelectedItems(i)
    j = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    'print the file path to sheet 1
    Cells(j, 1) = strPath

    Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    WordApp.Documents.Open strPath
    WordApp.Visible = True

    With WordApp.Documents.Content

    DocStats = WordApp.ReadabilityStatistics(strPath).Value
    MsgBox DocStats, vbOKOnly, "Hello"
    Cells(j, 2) = DocStats

    End With

Next i
End If

End Sub
```

Now I want to import the ReadabilityStatistics code from http://word.tips.net/T001784_Only_Showing_Readability_Statistics.html into this code so that along with logging the path, it would also log the readability stats of the word file (s). Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `With` block with

```
With WordApp.ActiveDocument.Content

For j = 1 To .ReadabilityStatistics.Count
  DocStats = DocStats & .ReadabilityStatistics(j)
  DocStats = DocStats & ": "
  DocStats = DocStats & .ReadabilityStatistics(j).Value
  DocStats = DocStats & vbCrLf
Next j

MsgBox DocStats, vbOKOnly, "Hello"
Cells(j, 2) = DocStats

End With
```